# Getting iCloud account details

Tags: ios7, icloud

I want to know what iCloud account is configured the iOS device, Is there any API to get the iCloud account details in iOS 7?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You have no access to any account details. The most you can do is

- Find out if iCloud is configured by calling `[NSFileManager ubiquityIdentityToken]`
- Find out if the account has changed by calling that method again to see if the value has changed or by observing `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification`.

You do not get to find out the user's account name or any other details about their account. None of that is relevant to using iCloud.